# React countup animation starts immediately after the page loading , should start when scrolled to the component (without jquery)

Tags: reactjs, counter, react-animations

I have a react single page app, with multiple components. For the 5th component(visible only when scrolled down) I have a counter . Now I am using react-countup library to achieve the counter function. However , the counter starts soon as the page is loaded . Is it possible for countup to begin once we scroll down to the component.
Animation happens only once(which is good)after the page is loaded, but I would like the counter not to begin soon after the page is loaded, but when user scrolls down to the component the first time.
My code looks like this:

```
    render() {
         return (
         <div className={style.componentName}>
         <h2>Heading</h2>
         <div className={style.col}>
         <div>My counter</div>
         <CountUp className={style.countup} decimals={1} start={0} end={25} suffix=" %" duration={3} />
        </div>
        </div>)}
```

Updated code:

```
    import CountUp, { startAnimation } from 'react-countup';
    import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

    class className extends Component {

        state = {
            scrollStatus: true
        };


        onVisibilityChange = isVisible => {
            if (isVisible) {
                if (this.state.scrollStatus) {
                    startAnimation(this.myCountUp);
                    this.setState({ scrollStatus: false });
                }
            }
        }
    render() {
             return (
            <div className={style.componentName}>
             <h2>Heading</h2>
             <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.onVisibilityChange} offset = {{ top: 
              10}} delayedCall>
             <CountUp className={style.countup} decimals={1} start={0} end={25} 
             suffix=" %" duration={3} ref={countUp => { this.myCountUp= countUp;}}/>
             </VisibilitySensor>
            </div>)}
}
```

Answer (score 35):

The API may have changed since last year. I manage to make this work with this code now :

```
import React from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <>
    <CountUp end={100} redraw={true}>
        {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
            <VisibilitySensor onChange={start} delayedCall>
                <span ref={countUpRef} />
            </VisibilitySensor>
        )}
    </CountUp>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

I use this component inside a tab, so the `redraw={true}` prop is only here to redraw the animation on tabChange.

Comment: this should be answer with current version

Comment: How do I make it run just once istead of everytime it enters viewport?

Comment: Clean and simple. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me after hours of fighting with the two libraries trying other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: `findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode` and work arounds?

Comment: export default not should be export default MyComponent ?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in React CountUp `5.X` there is a prop called `enableScrollSpy` which enables starting the animation when target is in view.
Thanks to @coding-spidy and his answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74401320/7918037) for highlighting this solution which is the easiest and simplest one.

Answer (score 9):

Per [React CountUp's README](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup/blob/master/README.md), you can use the `startAnimation` hook to manually kick off the animation. Combine this with something like [react-visibility-sensor](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor), and you can wait to kick off the animation until it is visible in the user's browser.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CountUp, {startAnimation} from 'react-countup';
import './App.css';
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

const style = {
  componentName: {},
  col: {},
  countup: {},
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onVisibilityChange = this.onVisibilityChange.bind(this); // Bind for appropriate 'this' context
  }

  onVisibilityChange(isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
      startAnimation(this.myCountUp);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.componentName}>
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <div className={style.col}>
          <div>My counter</div>
          <VisibilitySensor
            onChange={this.onVisibilityChange}
            delayedCall // Prevents react apps triggering elements as visible before styles are loaded
          >
            <CountUp className={style.countup} decimals={1} start={0} end={25} suffix=" %" duration={3}
                     ref={countUp => { this.myCountUp = countUp; }} // From react-countup README 
            />
          </VisibilitySensor>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As is, it will `startAnimation` every time you scroll to the countup. If you want to only do that once, just add a piece of state that gets set after the first render (and then prevent it from doing `startAnimation` again based on that altered state).

Less elegant (not recommended) ways to accomplish the same effect might include:

- Use the built-in animation triggers (i.e. changing the props `duration`, `end`, `start`) by setting them equal to some state that changes when the user scrolls down
- Leveraging the `onStart` prop, called before the animation starts, to delay starting the animation until the user scrolls down

EDIT: Update to address your second question

Unfortunately, it looks like the `react-countup` library doesn't expose a way to prevent `startAnimation` on startup.

But we can hack together a fairly elegant fix by manipulating the `end` prop using state instead:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CountUp, {startAnimation} from 'react-countup';
import './App.css';
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

const style = {
  componentName: {},
  col: {},
  countup: {},
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    didViewCountUp: false
  };


  onVisibilityChange = isVisible => {
    if (isVisible) {
      this.setState({didViewCountUp: true});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.componentName}>
        <h2 style={{fontSize: '40em'}}>Heading</h2>
        <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.onVisibilityChange} offset={{
          top:
            10
        }} delayedCall>
          <CountUp className={style.countup} decimals={1} start={0} end={this.state.didViewCountUp ? 25 : 0}
                   suffix=" %" duration={3} />
        </VisibilitySensor>
      </div>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: used state to set a value after first render. It works perfectly!  Thank you very much. :) But one small bug,the counter at the beginning  is at end count=25 and animation starts on scroll to the component. i.e there's a small amount of time before animation of 0-25 start.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the updated code? Will help to try it out and maybe can suggest a fix in the context of what you have

Comment: I updated the code. it is exactly as the code that ur answer. Using state to do the "startAnimation" just once.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my implementation. It just runs once and also doesn't re-render every time the component enters viewport to check visibility.

Dependencies:
 1. **react-countup** v.4.3.2
 2. **react-visibility-sensor** v.5.1.1

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

const Ticker = ({ className, ...rest }) => {
  const [viewPortEntered, setViewPortEntered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <CountUp {...rest} start={viewPortEntered ? null : 0}>
      {({ countUpRef }) => {
        return (
          <VisibilitySensor
            active={!viewPortEntered}
            onChange={isVisible => {
              if (isVisible) {
                setViewPortEntered(true);
              }
            }}
            delayedCall
          >
            <h4 className={className} ref={countUpRef} />
          </VisibilitySensor>
        );
      }}
    </CountUp>
  );
};

export default Ticker;
```

Here's how to use it:

```
<Ticker className="count" end={21} suffix="M+" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution using class based component
Note: *import two Libraries first run this code*
**react-visibility-sensor**
**react-countup**

```js
import React from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

class CountDown extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            
                <React.Fragment>
                    <CountUp start={0} end={100} prefix="+" duration="2">

                        {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
                            <VisibilitySensor onChange={start} delayedCall>
                                <span ref={countUpRef} />
                            </VisibilitySensor>
                        )}

                    </CountUp>
                </React.Fragment>
           

        )
    }
}

export default CountDown;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add below prop

**enableScrollSpy**: true

```
<CountUp enableScrollSpy={true} end={75}/>
```

Comment: Easiest solution of all as it's built-in already. Thank you for saving hours.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for that library have a way to manually start the counter. I would use that approach to start the counter once a user has scrolled to the required distance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CountUp, { startAnimation } from 'react-countup';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <CountUp className="CountUp" start={0} end={100} duration={3} ref={(countUp) => {
      this.myCountUp = countUp;
    }} />
    <button className="Button" onClick={(event) => {
      startAnimation(this.myCountUp);
    }}>Count me up!</button>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

[Link to Github](https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup). Read the README at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

you can have look at my functional component to achieve this

```
import React from "react";
    import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
    import CountUp from "react-countup";
    import VisibilitySensor from "react-visibility-sensor";

    export default function Counter() {
      const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);
      return (
        <Box component="div">
          <CountUp start={focus ? 0 : null} end={100} duration={5} redraw={true}>
            {({ countUpRef }) => (
              <div>
                <span ref={countUpRef} />
                <VisibilitySensor
                  onChange={isVisible => {
                    if (isVisible) {
                      setFocus(true);
                    } 
                  }}
                >
                  <a>+</a>
                </VisibilitySensor>
              </div>
            )}
          </CountUp>
        </Box>
      );
    }
```

Comment: This runs everytime component enters viewport while scrolling. Doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: hi @Sushmit I have edited the code you can take a look at it, I think it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

**react-visibility-sensor** doesn't seem to be maintained at the moment and produces warnings related to `findDOMNode` which is deprecated.

I've used **react-waypoint** in my functional component which makes the animation only trigger once when the user has the child of the waypoint component in view.

```
    // Ticker.tsx

import React, { useState } from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";
import { Waypoint } from "react-waypoint";

type TickerProps = {
  end: number;
  suffix: string;
}

const Ticker: React.FC<TickerProps> = ({ end, suffix }) => {
  const [viewPortEntered, setViewPortEntered] = useState(false);

  const onVWEnter = () => {
    setViewPortEntered(true);
  }

    return (
      <Waypoint onEnter={onVWEnter} >
        <div>
          {viewPortEntered && <CountUp end={end} suffix={suffix} start={0} /> }
        </div>
      </Waypoint>
    );
};

export default Ticker;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<CountUp
        className={styles.number}
        start={0}
        end={number}
        enableScrollSpy={true}
        scrollSpyDelay={0}
        suffix={index !== -1 ? "+" : ""}
/>
```

try this
scroll spy should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using [`react-in-viewport`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-in-viewport) package. Idea is to define this element and use `<CountUpInViewport>` instead of `<CountUp>`.

This example fires on the first entry. One could do variations on this to refire every time it enters/leaves the viewport.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import CountUp from 'react-countup';
import { useInViewport } from 'react-in-viewport';

let CountUpInViewport = props => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const { enterCount } = useInViewport(ref);
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {
        enterCount > 0 ?
        <CountUp key='in' {...props}></CountUp> :
        <CountUp key='out' {...props}></CountUp>  // ensures drawn when not visible
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the **enableScrollSpy** flag to achieve this.

```
<CountUp end={25} enableScrollSpy />
```

Also, If you want to start the animation every time it comes into focus, add the **scrollSpyOnce** flag and make it **false**.

```
<CountUp end={25} enableScrollSpy scrollSpyOnce={false} />
```