# React count up on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I'm using react-countup plugin to animate a counter from 0 to identified number and i wanted to make this counter works only once on scroll when it's revealed first time..
and I used this code using react visibility censor

```html
<CountUp start={0} end={4.8} duration={2} decimals={1}>
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
        <VisibilitySensor onChange={start}>
            <span ref={countUpRef} />
        </VisibilitySensor>
    )}
 </CountUp>
```

but then it's happening every time it's revealed in the page and i want it to happen only the first time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React countup animation starts immediately after the page loading , should start when scrolled to the component (without jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044090/react-countup-animation-starts-immediately-after-the-page-loading-should-start)

Comment: actually this was my first problem but i dealt with it using visibility sensor and this link was the reference i relied on..
but my problem now is that it's animating every time it's revealed on the page while scolling

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try setting a variable to local storage that you reference if `viewedOnce` is true or false [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I understood the idea and I'm trying to do so but I can't deal with the functionality of the library itself so please can you explain it with code