# Problem with react-countup (enableScrollSpy)

Tags: reactjs

I have the following problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup
The counter is working in the opposite direction. From bottom to top and not from top to bottom using the `enableScrollSpy: boolean (Enables start animation when target is in view.)`

[Sample .Gif with the problem](https://lightseg.com.br/imagens/LightSeg-Corretora-de-Seguros-_-Seguro-Transporte-de-Cargas-Google-Chrome-2022-08-02-12-16-41.gif)

My code:

```
  <CountUp
    className={styles.contadoresLine2}
    end={4000}
    enableScrollSpy="true"
    duration={1}
    separator={"."}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `react-countup` is having issues with the enableScrollSpy. A simple work around is to install `react-visibility-sensor` and use like below.

```
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';

  <CountUp end={400}>
    {({ countUpRef, start }) => (
      <VisibilitySensor onChange={start}>
        <span ref={countUpRef} />
      </VisibilitySensor>
    )}
  </CountUp>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hww9fa?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css,package.json,src%2Findex.js

https://github.com/glennreyes/react-countup/issues/699

[React countup animation starts immediately after the page loading , should start when scrolled to the component (without jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044090/react-countup-animation-starts-immediately-after-the-page-loading-should-start)